# Namservers (NO GLUE) on .EU domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, glue-record

I have two cPanel accounts with two different domains. one is sunrisetrip.com and the other sunriseholidays.eu. Both have the same nameservers, both are bought from the same registrar. the .com domain works while .eu one it does not. 
When i check the .EU my domain on intodns.com i get this:

```
ns1.forsunrise.com.   ['174.36.138.30'] (NO GLUE)   [TTL=86400] 
ns2.forsunrise.com.   ['174.36.138.30'] (NO GLUE)   [TTL=86400]
```

This makes no sense for me because everything is setup the same way and one domain is not pointing.

Any tips?

Comment: Did you read carefully the output from `intodns.com` for `sunriseholidays.eu` ? There are lot of errors. Read them carefully and you should find some clues : seems that `ns1.forsunrise.com` and `ns2.forsunrise.com` have no NS records for your domain `sunriseholidays.eu`

Comment: Can u help me out and tell me where i should look in order to add a NS record for those nameservers ? from domain registrar or WHM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the names of your nameservers are from an entirely different different domain in the case of `sunriseholidays.eu` no glue is to be expected (the `.eu` TLD servers are not supposed to have this glue). So that particular part of your question does not appear to be your actual problem.

It does however appear that your glue records for `ns1.forsunrise.com` and `ns2.forsunrise.com` (used with `sunrisetrip.com`) do not actually match the authoritative records.

Your glue says:

```
ns1.forsunrise.com.     172800  IN      A       37.48.83.137
ns2.forsunrise.com.     172800  IN      A       37.48.83.173
```

While the authority (`ns1hwy.name.com`, etc.) says:

```
ns1.forsunrise.com.     300     IN      A       174.36.138.30
ns2.forsunrise.com.     300     IN      A       174.36.138.30
```

And `174.36.138.30` does not respond whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please can u give me a suggestion on what i should do ? I have about two days fighting with this.

Comment: Which addresses are correct? `37.48.83.137` + `37.48.83.173`? If so, change the `A` records in the `forsunrise.com` zone to match this.